# Unirest POST sending unrecognized fields (io.vertx.core.json.DecodeException error)

Tags: java, json, vaadin, vert.x, unirest

I am trying to send over Java objects from my Vaadin frontend to Vertx backend with the click of a button using Unirest. In my POST function, I have an ObjectMapper that maps the Java object into a JSON string, before carrying out the POST to Vertx. However, once I receive this string in Vertx, I am getting extra fields that are not in my Vaadin. As seen in the error below, there is an extra 'width' and 'height', while my original is boxWidth and boxHeight. Previously on another run, I had an extra 'name' while my original was supposed to be boxName. Also, the json string can actually be successfully saved into a new file as seen in the code in UserService.java.

Error:

```
SEVERE: Unhandled exception
io.vertx.core.json.DecodeException: Failed to decode: Unrecognized field "width" (class io.vertx.starter.components.BoundingBox), not marked as ignorable (12 known properties: "boxHeight", "picID", "boxname", "boxcolour", "boxcategory", "boxWidth", "xcoordi", "ycoordi", "endY", "boxName", "bbID", "endX"])
 at [Source: (String)"{
  "xcoordi" : 356.0,
  "ycoordi" : 247.0,
  "boxWidth" : 216.0,
  "boxHeight" : 178.0,
  "endX" : 572.0,
  "endY" : 425.0,
  "picID" : "https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/k7MAAOSwPfZZyfJD/s-l300.png",
  "boxname" : "lamppost1",
  "boxcategory" : "lights",
  "boxcolour" : "Aqua",
  "boxName" : "lamppost1",
  "width" : 216.0,
  "height" : 178.0
}"; line: 13, column: 18] (through reference chain: io.vertx.starter.components.BoundingBox["width"])
```

Vaadin UserService.java:

```
package com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.service;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;
import com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.components.BoundingBox;
import com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.components.Canvas;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public class UserService {

    public JSONArray bbJsonArray;
    public JSONObject bbJsonObject;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserService.class);
    public static ArrayList<BoundingBox> bb = Canvas.getArrayBoxes();
    public String jsonInString;

public void postAnnotations() {

        HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = null;

        try {
            response = Unirest.post("http://localhost:9080/api/annotations")
                    .header("accept", "application/json")
                    .header("content-type", "application/json") 
                    .body(jsonInString)
                    .asJson();
        } catch (UnirestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void run() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        BoundingBox dummyBB = createDummyObject();

        try {
            // Convert object to JSON string and save into a file directly
            mapper.writeValue(new File("sample/file/path"), dummyBB);

//            // Convert object to JSON string
//            jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(dummyBB);
//            System.out.println(jsonInString);

            // Convert object to JSON string and pretty print
            jsonInString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(dummyBB);
            System.out.println(jsonInString);

        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(dummyBB);

        postAnnotations();

    }

    private BoundingBox createDummyObject() {

        BoundingBox dummyBB = new BoundingBox("", "", "", "", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

        for (int i = 0; i < bb.size(); i++) {

            dummyBB = new BoundingBox(bb.get(i).picID, bb.get(i).boxname, bb.get(i).boxcategory, bb.get(i).boxcolour, bb.get(i).xcoordi, bb.get(i).ycoordi, bb.get(i).boxWidth, bb.get(i).boxHeight, bb.get(i).endX, bb.get(i).endY);

        }

        return dummyBB;

    }
}
```

Vaadin BoundingBox.java:

```
package com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.components;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class BoundingBox {

    public double xcoordi = 0;
    public double ycoordi = 0;
    public double boxWidth = 0;
    public double boxHeight = 0;
    public double endX = 0;
    public double endY = 0;
//    public final int bbID;
    public String picID;
    public String boxname;
    public String boxcategory;
    public String boxcolour;
    private static final AtomicInteger COUNTER = new AtomicInteger();

    public BoundingBox(String picID, String boxname, String boxcategory, String boxcolour, double xcoordi, double ycoordi, double boxWidth, double boxHeight, double endX, double endY) {
//        this.bbID = COUNTER.getAndIncrement();
        this.picID = picID;
        this.boxname = boxname;
        this.boxcategory = boxcategory;
        this.boxcolour = boxcolour;
        this.xcoordi = xcoordi;
        this.ycoordi = ycoordi;
        this.boxWidth = boxWidth;
        this.boxHeight = boxHeight;
        this.endX = endX;
        this.endY = endY;
    }
//
//    public int getBbID() {
//        return bbID;
//    }

    public String getPicID() {
        return picID;
    }

    public void setPicID(String picID) {
        this.picID = picID;
    }

    public String getBoxName() {
        return boxname;
    }

    public void setName(String boxname) {
        this.boxname = boxname;
    }

    public String getBoxcategory() {
        return boxcategory;
    }

    public void setBoxcategory(String boxcategory) {
        this.boxcategory = boxcategory;
    }

    public String getBoxcolour() {
        return boxcolour;
    }

    public void setBoxcolour(String boxcolour) {
        this.boxcolour = boxcolour;
    }

    public double getXcoordi() {
        return xcoordi;
    }

    public void setXcoordi(double xcoordi) {
        this.xcoordi = xcoordi;
    }

    public double getYcoordi() {
        return ycoordi;
    }

    public void setYcoordi(double ycoordi) {
        this.ycoordi = ycoordi;
    }

    public double getWidth() {
        return boxWidth;
    }

    public void setWidth(double endX, double xcoordi) {
        boxWidth = endX - xcoordi;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return boxHeight;
    }

    public void setHeight(double endY, double ycoordi) {
        boxHeight = endY - ycoordi;
    }

    public double getEndX() {  // Bottom-right X coordinate of box
        return endX;
    }

    public void setEndX(double endX) {
        this.endX = endX;
    }

    public double getEndY() {  // // Bottom-right Y coordinate of box
        return endY;
    }

    public void setEndY(double endY) {
        this.endY = endY;
    }

    public JSONObject toJSON() {

        JSONObject bbJsonObject = new JSONObject();
        bbJsonObject.put("boxname", boxname);
        bbJsonObject.put("boxcategory", boxcategory);
        bbJsonObject.put("boxcolour", boxcolour);
        bbJsonObject.put("xcoordi", xcoordi);
        bbJsonObject.put("ycoordi", ycoordi);
        bbJsonObject.put("boxwidth", boxWidth);
        bbJsonObject.put("boxheight", boxHeight);

        return bbJsonObject;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" +
                "Name=" + boxname +
                ", Class=" + boxcategory +
                ", Colour=" + boxcolour +
                ", X=" + xcoordi +
                ", Y=" + ycoordi +
                ", Width=" + boxWidth +
                ", Height=" + boxHeight +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This unrelated to Vert.x, this pure Jackson :
If you don't want to decode additional properties annotate your class with :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

Comment: Hello, I have done this as you suggested but am still getting the same error.

Comment: I added @JsonProperty to my BoundingBox class and now I am getting  a 'org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '['.........' error instead

Comment: You're trying to decode to an array but you get a single json document. This is not the same error from your initial request.